# Ansible How to read and manipulate settings based on an acronym

Tags: ansible

What strategy you use to control custom settings? Using ini files or save files in yaml format ?!

For example I have settings for acronym of my establishment.

How do I access from my playbook these variables or custom data?

I want to read the settings conditionally. Based on the referenced acronym.

Like that:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts myplaybooy.yml my_acronym
```

Example structure where CAX, BAC and SIN are acronyms:

```
CAX

IP_SERVER = 200.253.167.1
IP_DB_MASTER = 200.253.167.20
IP_DB_SLAVE = 200.253.167.21
IP_MIRROR   = 200.253.167.13

BAC

IP_SERVER = 200.253.168.1
IP_DB_MASTER = 200.253.168.20
IP_DB_SLAVE = 200.253.168.21
IP_MIRROR   = 200.253.168.13

SIN

IP_SERVER = 200.253.169.1
IP_DB_MASTER = 200.253.169.20
IP_DB_SLAVE = 200.253.169.21
IP_MIRROR   = 200.253.169.13
```

The reason for this change is to adapt my playbook for the ansible-pull. In ansible-pull conditional tests like these not work.

```
- name: Download pub key acesso
  fetch: 
  src=~acesso/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 
  dest="{{role_path}}/../appserver/files/pub_keys/appservers/csa{{groupvar.server.acronym}}am/acesso.pub" flat=yes
  sudo: yes
  delegate_to: "{{hostvars['csa'+groupvar.server.acronym+'am'].ansible_ssh_host}}"
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['pdv'+groupvar.server.acronym]
  run_once: True
  ignore_errors: yes
```

I think this is due to the fact that ansible-pull look at inventory subsets.

Comment: Can you add a bit more context as to how you're using the variables.... depending on that, my rough guess would be to store those values in a dictionary and make the acronyms the keys and store them all in a yaml file... i.e.,
    --- 
    Acronyms: { SIN: IP_SERVER: 200.253.169.1, IP_DB_MASTER: 200.253.169.20 [...], BAC: { [...] }, CAX: [...] }. 
Then in your plays or roles, you could source them like so:
    ---
    debug: var={{Acronyms[ACRONYM].IP_SERVER}}
where ACRONYM is the specific ACRONYM you're wanting to use. But again, more context would be helpful.

Comment: In that moment I attribute the acronym that I want wish? I could use an external parameter. and the command line I quote the acronym, eg ansible-playbook -i hosts pdv.yml -e acronym CAX
That?! or is there a better way? I have several servers and configuring these servers depends on the acronym. If "CAX" the database IP is: XXX if "SIN" the database IP is: ZZZ

Comment: It seems those settings are host or datacenter specific. Can't these simply be group or host vars?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you. If you can post more from the playbook you're using, I can help you make this work for the actual tasks you're running.

This is the command-line syntax I used:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml --extra-vars "ACRONYM=SIN"`

playbook.yml:

```
---
- name: show vars
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
  - var_file.yml
  tasks:
  - debug:
     msg: IP_SERVER = {{Acronyms[ACRONYM].IP_SERVER}}
  - debug:
     msg: IP_DB_MASTER = {{Acronyms[ACRONYM].IP_DB_MASTER}}
  - debug:
     msg: IP_DB_SLAVE = {{Acronyms[ACRONYM].IP_DB_SLAVE}}
  - debug:
     msg: IP_MIRROR = {{Acronyms[ACRONYM].IP_MIRROR}}
```

var_file.yml:

```
Acronyms: {
 CAX:
  { IP_SERVER: 200.253.167.1,
    IP_DB_MASTER: 200.253.167.20,
    IP_DB_SLAVE: 200.253.167.21,
    IP_MIRROR: 200.253.167.13
  },
 BAC:
  { IP_SERVER: 200.253.168.1,
    IP_DB_MASTER: 200.253.168.20,
    IP_DB_SLAVE: 200.253.168.21,
    IP_MIRROR: 200.253.168.13
  },
 SIN:
  { IP_SERVER: 200.253.169.1,
    IP_DB_MASTER: 200.253.169.20,
    IP_DB_SLAVE: 200.253.169.21,
    IP_MIRROR: 200.253.169.13
  }
 }
```

This is my terminal output:

```
    PLAY [show vars] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "IP_SERVER = 200.253.169.1"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "IP_DB_MASTER = 200.253.169.20"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "IP_DB_SLAVE = 200.253.169.21"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "IP_MIRROR = 200.253.169.13"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: In my current playbook. I have many conditional checks based on the group in which the host is inserted.
It happens that I have a need to use the ansible-pull. And these checks I quoted broke my code. The ansible-pull does not look at inventory subset.
Example: groups['pdv'+groupvar.server.acronym]+['csa'+groupvar.server.acronym+'am'] if groupvar is defined else ([])
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['pdv'+groupvar.server.acronym]

Comment: @Ivanelson Can you edit your question and post a portion of your playbook in the question to get more context?